# how to create arraylist<Object> from variable?

Tags: java, arraylist, orm

i need to create an arraylist of objects but need to load name of the object from variable. 
I have this...

```
public store_table(String table_name){    
switch (table_name)
  case: "table_1" table_1_list=new ArrayList<Person>; break;
  case: "table_2" table_2_list=new ArrayList<Car>; break;
...
}
```

and i need to create something like this:

```
list=new ArrayList<table_name>;
```

Im reading data from database with several tables using ORM. So the table_name is also name of the object.

so here is more code...

```
store_into table(String table_name) throws SQLException{
query="SELECT * FROM " +table_name+" OFFSET"+offset+ " FETCH NEXT 50 ROOWS ONLY";
Statement st= conn.createStetement();
Resulset rs= st.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()){
case "Person": 
        person=new Person (rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6));
        person_list.add(person);

        break;
    case "Car": ... 
     break;

...
}
} rs.close();
st.close();
switch (table_name){
    case "Person": 
        Singleton.getInstance().populate_tabule(person_list);
        break;
    case "car": ...
     break;
} }
```

and here is how i print row

```
public void populate_table(ArrayList<Person> list){


    Object[] row=new Object[6];
    for(int i=0;i<offset_size;i++){
        row[0]=list.get(i).getId();
        row[1]=list.get(i).getName();
        row[2]=list.get(i).getBirthday();
        row[3]=list.get(i).getEmail();
        row[4]=list.get(i).getAddress();
        row[5]=list.get(i).getSalary();

        view.setModel(row); 
    }
```

Comment: Try this list=new ArrayList<(Object)table_name>;

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: @MetalSalmon, kindly go through my answer and let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: list=new ArrayList<(Object)table_name>; doesnt work

Comment: After creating `ArrayList<table_name>`, to what will you assign it? Something like this `List list = new ArrayList<table_name>()`?

Comment: In your code, what will you do with the list you just created? For example, `case: "table_1" table_1_list=new ArrayList<Person>; break;` what will you do with `table_1_list` ?

Comment: @prasanth yes i need something like that

Comment: Can you explain bit more about your problem? Because I feel that you can create a generic ArrayList instead of creating one for each table name.

Comment: Will you be adding anything to the list?

Comment: @prasanth i will store several rows from database table table_name into array list table_1_list, then print them into Jtable wher user can edit them.

Comment: If you are creating an ArrayList based on table name, how will it help you with printing them in JTable? Why cant you create an ArrayList<Object>?

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: @prasanth I have created that as i showed in code.. that is working good and im able to print it and edit it. but im just wondering... because i have to use switch when creating array lists, then when i  store rows into them, then when i printing tables, editing and so on...

Comment: Do you type cast to `Person` or `Car` when editing the object?

Comment: Can you show us the code which prints, edits? Also I want to know how you call `store_table`

Comment: @prasanth i dont cast... program is working but i want to do it with better code

Comment: Why can't you just create `new ArrayList<Object>();` ?

Comment: I can... but i have 10 tables= 10 arraylists and i need to use switch 3 times so i was wondering if there is better solution for that.

Comment: I put up an answer that is a bit generic; if you put up some more "requirements" (why you want to things!) I might be able to give more specific advise. And no, using `List<Object>` doesnt make sense conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your whole "mental" model is deficient. As soon as you start creating variables that are named a1, a2, ... followed by writing code that does things explicitly for each variable - chances are that you are doing wrong.

In that sense: you don't use lists because you can; because you thought about building a mental model of the aspects in the real world that you want to express.

First of all, you should probably use some kind of [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) framework to do such things for you (your code is nothing else but attempting to build similar functionality  yourself).

Beyond that; as said: you should rather step back and improve your object model.

Answer (score -1):

You could make a HashMap where you have all the possible ArrayLists already made and then the key value is a string with the table name.

something like:

```
private final Map<String, ArrayList> TableArrays = new HashMap<>();

TableArrays.put("Person" , new ArrayList<Person>);
TableArrays.put("Car", new ArrayList<Car>);

ArrayList getTableArray(String table_name) {
    return TableArrays.get(table_name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So, you want to create `ArrayList`*s* of `Object`*s* of type as `table_name`

`switch` has the limitation of comparing actual values rather than values assigned to objects. 
For example, you are **not allowed to do** something like

```
switch (table_name) {
    case temp1:
        System.out.println("This is test1");
        break;
    case temp2:
        System.out.println("This is test2");
        break;
    }
```

You are **allowed to do**

```
switch (table_name) {
    case "test1":
        System.out.println("This is test1");
        break;
    case "test2":
        System.out.println("This is test2");
        break;
    }
```

I recommend moving from a `switch` to multiple `if-else` statements to solve this purpose.

So you might have a Person class as

```
class Person {
    int data;

    Person(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and a Car class as

```
class Car {
    int data;

    Car(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Therefore, you will create ArrayLists in the following fashion

```
public class Store_table {
    List<Person> personList;
    List<Car> carList;

    Store_table(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Person) {
            personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
        } else if (o instanceof Car) {
            carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: thank you but this is no sulution for me... the switch is working good... but i have to use switch so many times thats my problem. In your solution i would have to use if clausule so many times too.

Comment: Hi @MetalSalmon, I am curious to know if your problem was solved and how you approached it.